# <BEA-101024> Unsupported error status code for error-page in web.xml

Tags: servlets, weblogic, web.xml, custom-error-pages

We use weblogic to deploy our application and so far it was working fine, but encountered the following exception and not able to proceed with the application. The url seems to be down all the time.

> <BEA-101024> Unsupported error status code for error-page in web.xml.

And the code in `web.xml` is as follows

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>100</error-code>
    <location>/jsp/main/http_error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Any help on this is very much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change or add the webapp dtd to a newer one in WEB.XML. Weblogic is particularly strict with theese. Then you can add error-page handlers.

ciaooo

EDIT: how do you get an HTTP 100 from weblogic ? If my memory is right status 100 is CONTINUE and should be handled silently (without producing an error)

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>it.bigmike.servlet.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>LoginLoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  

  <error-page>
   <error-code>400</error-code>
   <location>/web/errore.html</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>/web/errore.html</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
   <error-code>403</error-code>
   <location>/web/errore.html</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
   <error-code>500</error-code>
   <location>/web/errore.html</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
   <error-code>503</error-code>
   <location>/web/errore.html</location>
  </error-page>
```

EDIT2: this web.xml works perfectly for me on weblogic 10.3

Comment: The one that we use is "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2.3.dtd"> and this seems to be the latest version.

Comment: Yes Mike, i agree with you, but that was just a sample code, so whatever error code we use, the exception still occurs.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the source sample. I found out what is causing the exception. The requirement is to handle all the server errors, so we have 500 through 510, 598 and 599. The specification of error codes - 510, 598 and 599 throws this exception, but have no clue why it is so.... You suggestion on this is highly appreciated. Thanks